# How to use a variable from a component in another in Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, components, scopes

I was wondering if it is possible to use variable values from one component into another one without having to use the template of the first one, just need the value of the variable nothing else.The problem it present when i change de value of varible and when i import it, the value doesnt change. Is it possible?

Ive try to import variable using this.fotoTobillo.imageTobillo and using a get method, but the resul is the same

FotoTobilloPage.ts

```
export class FotoTobilloPage implements OnInit {

imageTobillo: string;

constructor(private camera: Camera) {
 }

ngOnInit() {

}

public getimageTobillo() {
  return this.imageTobillo;
}
public onClick() {
  this.imageTobillo = 'NewValue';
}
}
```

FormularioPage.ts

```
export class FormularioPage implements OnInit {

imagenPie: string;
imagenTobillo: string;

constructor( private fotoTobillo: FotoTobilloPage ) {
  this.imagenTobillo = this.fotoTobillo.getimageTobillo;
  console.log(this.imagenTobillo);
}
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.imagenTobillo);
}
}
```

I expect that i can change the value of FotoTobilloPage.imageTobillo and i can obtain the value in FormularioPage

Comment: Is it a child component? You can add it as an input variable and listen for any changes as an output. Or you could put the variable in a service and read the changes from there.

Comment: what  approach you  tried to pass the value from one component to another?

Comment: You may try ngOnchanges() life cycle hoot to detect the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the method from a `component` by injecting it in `constructor` you just have to make a service.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FotoTobilloService {

    imageTobillo: string;

    constructor(private camera: Camera) {
    }

    getimageTobillo() {
        return this.imageTobillo;
    }
    public onClick() {
        this.imageTobillo = 'NewValue';
    }
}
```

Save the above code in a `.ts` file. Add it to the `provider` array in your `app.module.ts`.

Then `import` the class in your `component` to use it...

```
export class FormularioPage implements OnInit {

    imagenPie: string;
    imagenTobillo: string;

    constructor( private fotoTobillo: FotoTobilloService ) {
        this.imagenTobillo = this.fotoTobillo.getimageTobillo();
        console.log(this.imagenTobillo);
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.imagenTobillo);
    }
}
```